# How to send strings/commands to stdin

Tags: vala

While testing programs it would be nice to be able to pump strings into stdin for processing (libvala-0.36 on VSCode 1.15.0-insider/Linux Mint 18.2). Below is just for illustration, but stdin.puts/stdin.flush doesn't seem to work. How can I pump keystrokes/strings into stdin?

```
 private void test_func(){
    ...do stuff
    stdin.puts("""{"event":"server.connected","params":{"version":"0.0.1","pid":0}}""");
    ...do stuff 
    stdin.puts("exit\r\n");
 }
 public static int main (string[] args) {
    string line;
    ...do stuff 

 #if DEBUG
    test_func();
 #endif

    while ((line = stdin.read_line ()) != null) {
       line = line.strip ();
       if (line.length > 0) {
          if (line == "exit") break;
          gJsonRPC.handle_request (line);
          }
       }
    ...do stuff 
    }
```

Update:
Have not found functionality similar to .Net "SendKeys" class in GLib, so temporarily settled on this method....

```
  public static void SendKeys(string sKeys) {
     //--------------------------------------------------------------
     //OSS:Hack:SendKeys
     //--------------------------------------------------------------
     char[] _keys = sKeys.to_utf8();
     for (int i = _keys.length; i >= 0; i--)
        stdin.ungetc (_keys[i]);
     //--------------------------------------------------------------
     }
```

@Lasall suggested FileStream.open(¨/dev/stdin¨, ¨w¨), so I try that next.

Answer (score 2):

[`GLib.stdin`](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.stdin.html) really is just a [`GLib.FileStream`](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.FileStream.html).

You can encapsulate your processing code in a function that takes a FileStream like this:

```
public void my_processing_func (FileStream stream) {
   while ((line = stream.read_line ()) != null) {
      line = line.strip ();
      if (line.length > 0) {
         if (line == "exit") break;
         gJsonRPC.handle_request (line);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then in your main you can conditionally use either your test data or stdin:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
   var stream = test_func ();
#else
   var stream = stdin;
#endif
   my_processing_func (stream);
```

I probably wouldn't use DEBUG, but some more descriptive name like TEST_DATA, also it might be better to use proper unit testing and write a test program instead of #ifdefing your main program.

Comment: Thanks Jens, I already have separate unit tests. The code above was merely to provide a SO illustration of the stdin problem.  Any ideas as how I can pump strings into stdin? My stdin.puts above do not seem to work.

Comment: @George: stdin is read only. You can directly write to stdout or manually open with FileStream.open(¨/dev/stdin¨, ¨w¨) - same underlying file stream anyway. You´ll run into sync problems however since your changes might not get buffered until read by read_line.

Comment: I wouldn't even try in the first place, it only opens a can of worms where you don't know whether stdin is really the standard input. Instead either test your methods apart from the main program or if you really have to run "fake" input into your program write a shell script with pipe redirection instead that does `./myprog < someinput.json`.